# Increment a key's value (+1) within a series of objects contained in an array that's held in useState

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, spread-syntax

```
const = [items, setItems] = useState([{ name: "foo", wait: 1 }, { name: "bar", wait: 5 }])
```

I need to increase the key's value, **wait**, by 1 for all objects inside items.

Here is my attempt so far...

```
setItems(items.map(e => [...e, e.wait++]))
```

I get some crazy error... I'm not sure if I should use a spread operator or something close to what I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` should return the object instead of array.

```js
const items = [
  { name: "foo", wait: 1 },
  { name: "bar", wait: 5 },
];

const updated = items.map((item) => ({ ...item, wait: item.wait + 1 }));

// setItems(items.map(item => ({...item, wait: item.wait + 1})));

console.log(updated);
```